# Rake db:migration aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a unfinished project that a developer just didn't finish and didn't leave any documentation about the installation process. I've downloaded the production directory to my windows machine (running InstantRails 2), I created the databases as required in the `database.yml` and I tried to run the `rake:db:migrate --trace` but I'm receiving the following error message:

```
(in D:/projects/broke2)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Admin
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:279:in `load_missing_constant'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `const_missing'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `const_missing'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:285:in `constantize'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:284:in `each'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:284:in `constantize'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:143:in `constantize'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:481:in `migrations'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:15:in `inject'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:465:in `each'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:465:in `inject'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:465:in `migrations'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:431:in `migrate'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `up'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:356:in `migrate'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/tasks/databases.rake:99
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:617:in `call'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:617:in `execute'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:612:in `each'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:612:in `execute'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:578:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:571:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:564:in `invoke'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2019:in `invoke_task'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `each'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2036:in `standard_exception_handling'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1991:in `top_level'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1970:in `run'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2036:in `standard_exception_handling'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1967:in `run'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/bin/rake:31
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/bin/rake:19
```

I'm a regular Rails developer (it's not my first app) but I never saw this error and I don't have a clue where to start to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes Rails will throw this error if there's a syntax error where Admin is defined.

Try looking for admin.rb and make sure that it parses.

Also, you may want to try running the migrations one at a time (`rake db:migrate VERSION=1`, etc.) to see if that helps you track down which migration causes the error, or if it is a problem simply booting the application.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you had a migration that created a table and added some data using a model. Later in the project the model got renamed or removed (as did the table maybe?). As the model no longer existed the migrations failed to run, but no one noticed as by that point they were only running a few migrations at a time, not from a clean database.

The lesson here ... if you rename models or tables (or update their validations and fields) then check your migrations run from scratch as well on the current production version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your problem is in the `uninitialized constant Admin` part of your migration issue. Have you tried finding where Admin is initialized and including the path to that wherever you're using it? (Also, what's the contents of the rake task you're running?)

Answer (score 0):

It don't points me where i have a Admin constant. There is a way to check at least where should I look? my models, my controllers, etc?

rake db:migrate VERSION=1, gives me a error already. As I told you, am I just trying to finish a project unfinished by another guy.

How can i do a migration file per file?

Regards,

Victor

Comment: Make a backup of your database, then drop it completely and try to migrate to VERSION=1. Then VERSION=2, etc.

The Admin constant is probably a model. Is there a file in your app called admin.rb?

Comment: it's strange. i have a 001_admin.rb but there is no Admin model. in my 001_admin.rb it tries to write in Default class.. make sense?

Comment: anyway i fixed. i just renamed the file to 001_default.rb and worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the schema all at once instead of executing each migration:

rake db:schema:load

As RichH said there might have been a change to the schema not reflected in the migrations